# Protocol Buffer

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I'm trying to get my head around protocol buffers. I understood the basic stuff, but now I'm trying to define the following javascript object as a .proto. Using the [Node.js gRPC Library](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/src/node)

```
const listsSchema = new Schema({
    id: { type: String, required: true },
  id_str: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: true },
  slug: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now },
  updatedAt: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now },
  track: { type: Boolean, 'default': false },
  lastTrackedTweet: [
    { 
      id: { type: String, required: true },
      id_str: { type: String, required: true },
      createdAt: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now },
      updatedAt: { type: Date, 'default': Date.now }
        }
    ]
});
```

This is what I have come up with, but it is getting rejected.

```
syntax = "proto3";

package lists;

service Lists {
  rpc FindLists (ListRequest) returns (ListReply) {}
}

message ListRequest {
  struct params = 1;
}

message ListReply {
  repeated struct List = 1;
}

message List {
 int64 id = 1;
 string id_str = 2;
 string name = 3;
 string description = 4;
 string slug = 5;
 Timestamp createdAt = 6;
 Timestamp updatedAt = 7;
 bool track = 8;
 repeated struct LastTrackedTweet = 9;
}

message LastTrackedTweet {
  int64 id = 1;
  string id_str = 2;
  Timestamp createdAt = 3;
  Timestamp updatedAt = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The documentation is not so good on advanced examples:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package lists;

service Lists {
  rpc FindLists (ListRequest) returns (ListReply) {}
}

message ListRequest {
 string query = 1
}

message ListReply {
  repeated List list = 1;
}

message List {
 int64 id = 1;
 string id_str = 2;
 string name = 3;
 string description = 4;
 string slug = 5;
 string createdAt = 6;
 string updatedAt = 7;
 bool track = 8;
 repeated LastTrackedTweet lastTrackedTweet = 9;
}

message LastTrackedTweet {
  int64 id = 1;
  string id_str = 2;
  string createdAt = 3;
  string updatedAt = 4;
}
```